# VB.Net insert multiple records

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have several rows in DataGridView control. And i want to insert each row into database. I tried like this. But it gives error that parameter is already added. How to add parameter name once and then add values each time and execute it each time?

```
    Using connection As New SqlCeConnection(My.Settings.databaseConnectionString)
        Using command As New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO table_master(item, price) VALUES(@item, @price)", _
                                        connection)

            connection.Open()

            For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvMain.Rows
                If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Cells(1).Value)) Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", r.Cells(1).Value.Trim)
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", r.Cells(2).Value)


                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
            Next

        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the parameters outside the loop and inside the loop update only their values

```
Using connection As New SqlCeConnection(My.Settings.databaseConnectionString)
    Using command As New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO table_master(item, price) VALUES(@item, @price)", _
                                    connection)

        connection.Open()

        ' Create and add the parameters, just one time here with dummy values or'
        ' use the full syntax to create each single the parameter'
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", "")
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", 0)

        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvMain.Rows
            If (Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Cells(1).Value)) Then

                command.Parameters("@item").Value = r.Cells(1).Value.Trim
                command.Parameters("@price").Value = r.Cells(2).Value
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next

    End Using
End Using
```

Using AddWithValue is a nice shortcut, but has its drawbacks. For example, it is unclear what datatype is required for the column `Price`. Using the Parameter constructor you could specify the exact datatype for the parameter and avoid a possible conversion mistake

```
Dim p = new SqlCeParameter("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal)
command.Parameters.Add(p)
......
```