# Copy VB Datatable To Local Database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sql-server-ce

I'm Using And Datagridview To load Data From Excelsheet using OleDbConnection
After Editing Some Rows In Datagridview I Want To Store It For further use 
So I just Want To that Data to Store in local VB database I can insert Single Values To local databse using following code but don't know to how to insert all of these rows to databse

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("Insert Into Users(name, phone) Values('phenry', ‘88866677’)", con)

If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.close
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a loop over all of the rows?

Comment: But I Have About 8000 Rows in database So it could take a lot of time to execute all of query seperately. . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.Net insert multiple records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340063/vb-net-insert-multiple-records)

Comment: You should probably use something like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17340117/341065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my SqlCeBulkCopy library for inserting datatables to SQL Server Compact

Comment: Thanks I have already referred it But I was searching for easier one because i have variantly changing column names So it becomes some ockward